# change icons with app.directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

I have a menu with several icons, which when I click on one of them, change the icon and when I click again in the same icon, returns to its original state, but if I click on one and then I click on another, the first icon should back to its original state, but it does not and I'm not sure why it is not modified.

The HTML is this:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-controller="customerInformationController">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
                <menuico linkTo="main" imageDefault="ico_menu_off.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <menuico linkTo="customerSearch" imageDefault="ico_search_off.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <menuico linkTo="#" imageDefault="ico_user_off.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <img src="img/logo_santander.png" class="logo" />
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="navbar-manager">{{nombreGestor}}</li>
            <li><a ng-click="closeTabs();" class="close-session"><img src="img/ico_closesession.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm using a AngularJS directive to make such changes icons. The Angular code is:

```
app.directive('menuico', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
        scope: {},
    template: '<a href="#{{route}}"><img src="img/{{image}}" /></a>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var active = false;
            var defaultRoute = "";
            var activeIcon = "ico_close.png";

            scope.image = attrs.imagedefault;
            scope.route = attrs.linkto;
            elem.bind("click", function() {
                active = !active;
                if(active) {
                    scope.route = defaultRoute;
                    scope.image = activeIcon;
                } else {
                    scope.route = attrs.linkto;
                    scope.image = attrs.imagedefault;
                }
            });
    }
  };
});
```

What I need, for example, is that if I clicked in the "ico_search_off.png", this change to "ico_close.png", and if I clicked now in "ico_user_off.png", this one change to "ico_close.png" and the first one have to change to the original status, that is, to "ico_search_off.png", but the first one doesn't change and remains in the current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it change when you click on a different one? They are different directives with their own scope and their own local variables so they don't talk to each other.

You need to set up some kind of communication between the directives.

My preferred way of doing this is to bind a click event to $document which fires every time the page is clicked (anywhere). This event could then trigger the firing of an event on $rootscope which tells all your menu items to reset themselves. The only tricky bit is that you need to check the event.target that was clicked and not close the one you're trying to open.

The other (possibly better) solution is to write an angular service and inject it onto your directive which keeps track of all your menu items and which ones are in which state. This may be overkill for a simple menu icon directive though.

Comment: you know where I can see one example like this using angular service? Thanks

Comment: Try looking at the Angular UI github code page. They do this kind of thing a lot.

Comment: By the way Derek, you've asked 7 questions on this site since you joined and you've not awarded a single upvote or correct answer on any of them. People aren't going to help you if you can't even click a little up arrow or tick in return.

Answer (score 0):

try this below,

```
app.directive('menuico', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<a href="#{{route}}"><img src="img/{{image}}" /></a>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var active = false;
            var defaultRoute = "";
            var activeIcon = "ico_close.png";

            scope.image = attrs.imagedefault;
            scope.route = attrs.linkto;
            elem.bind("click", function() {
                active = !active;
                if(active) {
                    scope.route = defaultRoute;
                    scope.image = activeIcon;
                } else {
                    scope.route = attrs.linkto;
                    scope.image = attrs.imagedefault;
                }
                $rootScope.$emit('resetElements', scope.route);
            });
            $rootScope.$on('resetElements', function(event, data) {
                if(data != scope.route) {
                    scope.route = attrs.linkto;
                    scope.image = attrs.imagedefault;    
                }    
            });
        }
    };
});
```

so you will be listening to resetElements event any time there is a click event.  all other buttons that don't match the clicked route will be reset.

Comment: I'm trying to make this example, I'm trying to change to see if it works, but when I click on an icon, modify, I click the next also modified, but also modified first stay, but when I click on any of them again, the two icons back to their original state.
I don't know so much Angular and I don't know how to modify it correctly

Comment: can you explain in simple terms please?

Comment: the icons do not change properly, as in the picture, I click on the icons and both change to the icon "X", but if one is modified (with the icon "X") and I click on the other, the first should return to normal and the other modify the icon "X". I don't know if I've explained well

Comment: For example, if I clicked in the "ico_search_off.png", this change to "ico_close.png", and if I clicked now in "ico_user_off.png", this one change to "ico_close.png" and the first one have to change to the original status, that is, to "ico_search_off.png", but the first one doesn't change and remains in the current state

Comment: If you do it this way, remember to remove all the $rootscope stuff when the scope is destroyed to stop memory leaks.